# Configuration to point an X tty to a separate system?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, xorg, tty

Specifically, I have an Ubuntu 10.04 system with a headless Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine, and I'm looking for a way to have it set up so pressing ctrl+alt+F8 will take me into another X client which is connected to an X server on the vm (with gdm appropriately displayed at startup, etc.). As in, my startup script should spin up the headless machine and then immediately perform a "startx" pointed at the vm.